# Do different files always have different MD5 or SHA1 hash codes?

Tags: hash

Do different files always lead to different MD5 or SHA1 hash codes?

Comment: well, that's the whole point of a hash function, edge cases aside...

Answer (score 9):

@PeterHarmann's answer is entirely correct, but to add to it: Secure hash algorithms (which MD5 was intended to be, and which is literally what "SHA" stands for) are ***supposed*** to be highly resistant to [collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack) where any two inputs have the same output. While such collisions will always exist for any algorithm that can take a longer (in terms of arbitrary bits of data) input than its output, *finding* them is supposed to be near-impossible. Ideally, doing so requires a brute-force attack on an infeasibly large search space, even when utilizing a [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack). In other words, while it's true that different files *cannot* always have different hash digests, in practice it's supposed to be possible to act as though they do.

SHA1 is deprecated because it has been demonstrated to be vulnerable to a collision attack, as Peter's link shows. MD5 is even worse, though; it has been demonstrated to be vulnerable to a *chosen-prefix* collision attack, where two distinct inputs can have suffixes appended to cause them to have the same hash digest. This was demonstrated as a way to break the protections afforded by cryptographic signatures (one of the key uses of secure hashes) by creating colliding X.509 certificates, allowing an attacker to generate a fraudulent certificate (with their own public key) that has the same hash and therefore the same signature as a valid certificate signed by a trusted certificate authority. The [Flame malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_(malware)) used a fraudulent certificate purportedly signed by Microsoft, which was possible because Microsoft had a CA that was still issuing MD5-signed certificates.

Answer (score 6):

No they don't. If you think about it, sha1 output has 160 bits. There are more than 2^160 possible files, therefore there must be multiple (infinitely many) potential files that have the same hashes. The problem is finding them.

[Here](https://shattered.io/) are two files that have the same sha1.

Comment: aside from those two files, how often does sha1 collide?

Comment: @dandavis if you are not actively looking for a collision, to a single file then about once in 2^160 ~10^48. So a number with 48 zeroes. You will pretty much never find a collision by accident. Or 10^24 if you compare every one with every one. So one collision in one hexalion files? Is it hexalion?

Comment: There are not infinitely many possible input files. There are "only" 2^(2^64-1) possible inputs, since the maximum length of an input is 2^64-1 due to the length encoding in the Merkle–Damgård padding.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically they don't, and this is known as the "[Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)". However, the probability to have 2 identical hashes is very small.
The Pigeonhole principle for hashes in brief:

- A hash has a specific bit length, say *a*. For SHA256, *a=256*.
- As a result, there can be *2^a* unique hash values. For SHA256, this is *2^256* (2 raised to 256) unique hash values.
- If the file size is *b* bits, then we can have *2^b* unique files.
- The size of a file is much greater than *a* (otherwise we wouldnt need hashes). This can only happen if different files map to the same hash.

However, it is highly difficult for somebody to produce a second file having the same hash. This is because of the hashing algorithm properties.

Answer (score 0):

Not always. Addition to the previous well explaining answers, Google has an announcement for the collision for SHA-1 algorithm:

[(Google) Announcing the first SHA1 collision](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html) .

Moreover, MD5 collision has been announced in 2004 referring from [Cryptosense](https://cryptosense.com/blog/google-announces-full-sha-1-collision-what-it-means/).